# Watir-webdriver click action returns true/success but does not really do the click action

Tags: click, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a span element which cascades from div, which to look at is like a button with text "Okay,got it." . Its HTML is as follows:

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline defaultButton xwtButton xwt-TextButton xwt-TextButtonFocused dijitFocused" role="presentation" widgetid="xwt_widget_form_TextButton_2">
    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick">
      <span id="xwt_widget_form_TextButton_2" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" aria-labelledby="xwt_widget_form_TextButton_2_label" role="button" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" tabindex="0">
         <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon" data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode"></span>
         <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">\u25cf</span>
         <span id="xwt_widget_form_TextButton_2_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText" data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode">Okay, got it.</span>
</span>
```

So I tried most types of click:

```
@browser.span(:text => /Okay/).click
@browser.span(:text => /Okay/).fire_event("onclick")
@browser.span(:text => /Okay/).double_click
@browser.span(:text => /Okay/).send_keys :enter etc
```

I also used, focus, hover..I see that all these locates element and does click (as I see the element kind shows reaction on clicking by webdriver, but the button kind of fades and thats it, nothing happens further, no error)
But I noticed its html changes to on one click, but nothing happens if I try to again click :

```
<span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline defaultButton xwtButton xwt-TextButton xwt-TextButtonHover digitHover xwt-TextButtonFocused xwt-TextButtonHoverFocused dijitHoverFocused dijitFocused" role="presentation" widgetid="xwt_widget_form_TextButton_2">
```

Please help me how to handle this UI click

Comment: Never mind, I found it working by using :span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode"

Comment: Out of curiosity, what browser are you using? Is this Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

When you have nested spans like that, where only the innermost has text, ALL the spans effectively have the same text.  So if you try to select by text alone, watir is just going to return the first one it finds that matches, which is most likely the outer level container.  Which may not be the one that needs to receive the click action.

So you need to select by some other parameter, such as perhaps the class  (which based on comments is what you ended up doing)

```
@browser.span(:class => "dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode").click
```

The tricky part with a structure like that is finding which of that set of nested spans is the one that needs to get clicked.. that is mostly experimentation.. IRB is your friend there.

btw, whatever library your developers are using.. man the resulting html and DOM structure makes my brain hurt..